# Multi-Monitor Setup Won't Detect on Display Port

Tags: display, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I'm unable to get all 3 of my monitors to detect on a new computer build.  Last night I had all 3 working by plugging 2 into display ports and 1 into HDMI, but this morning I tried to change out the HDMI for another display port and rearrange the order they were plugged in while the computer was off.  When I turned the computer back on, only the side monitors were detected and the center screen had no signal.  I tried to rearrange the cables back to their original configuration and then only one screen detected on display port.  I can get the other side monitor to detect only if I switch it back to HDMI but not on the display port, and I can't get the center screen to detect again no matter which display port I plug it into, or even by changing display port cables entirely.

This is a brand new computer I just built and the drivers are definitely up to date.  The graphics card is a reused EVGA RTX 2070 XC.

Answer (score 0):

## Finding the Culprit

### Faulty Cables

The first thing you want to rule out is a faulty DisplayPort cable or rather multiple faulty cables.

As you have mentioned that you assembled a new build, it is likely you ordered the same cable multiple times, which would mean that they are all from the same bunch and therefore have the same, possibly bad or suboptimal characteristics.

Length is also important, [as two meters are usually the guaranteed maximum length to support higher speed transmission modes (i.e. HBR and UHBR modes)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Cable_length).

Also, cables that previously worked with lower resolution or refresh rate monitors, might not or not reliably work with higher resolution or refresh rate monitors.

They can also get damaged by mechanical stress over the course of their lifetime, mainly due to bending. Rearranging your cables could have just been enough stress to cause this, especially if the cables are older.
This is not always easy to recognize, as the failure can both be in the cable and/or on the plug, more specifically the plug's solder joint. In the latter case, the plug will likely wobble when you apply stress on it.

Linus Tech Tips has a good video on testing DisplayPort cable quality and they also [explained how DisplayPort devices negotiate speeds and how cables can fail during link training](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vn2vdQZhs0w&t=477s).

### Unreliable, Wobbly and Worn-Out Connectors

Ports on hardware that has been in use for a long time, can fail due to mechanical stress as well. Both monitor and GPU video ports can be affected by this, become unreliable and possibly start to wobble just the same way the plugs on display cables can. It is less likely than a cable fault, but can still happen.

### Incorrect Multi-Display Settings in the Operating System

If faulty connections are not the cause of your problems, you might want to inspect the display settings of your operating system. It could be that the monitor indeed connected and got recognized but the display is set to disconnected.

Check with <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> that the project setting is set to "Extend".

Alternatively, or if it did not work for all monitors, go to the display settings with <kbd>Right-Click</kbd>→`Display settings` and scroll down to the section *Multiple monitors* to check if the display is set to `Disconnect this display` and set it to `Extend these displays` or whatever you would like.